# Boltzmann equation for a collisionless medium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

In the [derivation of the Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation#The_force_and_diffusion_terms) (link to Wikipedia) for a collisionless gas it is assumed that: 
$$
f\left( \vec{r} + \frac{ \vec{p} }{m} \Delta t, \ \vec{p} + \vec{F} \Delta t, \ t + \Delta t \right) = f\left( \vec{r}, \vec{p}, t \right)
$$

What is the reasoning for this expression.

Comment: Hint: In the absence of collisions all particles are independent.

Comment: (so the phase space density changes just due to the movement of the particles in phase space).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reasoning for this expression

This is another way of expressing a specific form of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) given by:
$$
\frac{d \ f\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}, t \right)}{d t} = 0
$$
where $f\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}, t \right)$ is the phase space density.  It is another way of saying that the *phase space density is conserved along trajectories in* [*phase space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) [i.e., a trajectory is a curve in $\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p} \right)$ space] or that *phase space is incompressible for this system*.

It simply means that $f\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}, t \right)$ does not change.

## **Additional and/or Related Answers**

- Discussion of meaning of trajectories at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237974/59023
- Discussion of collisionless Boltzmann equation (i.e., the [Vlasov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation)) at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177972/59023
- Discussion of affect of instabilities on Liouville's theorem at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300053/59023